# Unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: Internal error occurred

Tags: kubernetes, helm, prometheus, minikube

I am running a local Kubernetes cluster with Minikube on a Windows machine using `--driver=hyperv`.
I am trying to set up an HPA (HorizontalPodAutoscaler) based on Pods custom metrics. Using Helm, I deployed the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) to scrape more advanced metrics and everything is working fine. 
I then deployed the [prometheus-adapter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus-adapter) with Helm and defined rules so that the adapter monitors nodes/pods resources and a set of custom metrics. After deploying the adapter, I'm able to query the metrics API with `kubectl top pod` as well as the custom metrics API with `kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1`.
However the HPA and myself are unable to get any metrics out of the custom metrics API. `kubectl describe hpa/my-hpa` displays the following warning in the events section:
 `FailedGetPodsMetric horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metric bytes_per_second: unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: Internal error occurred: unable to fetch metrics`
The prometheus adapter is correctly linked to Prometheus, I'm using the default K8S namespace and the custom rules defined for the adapter are as follow:

```
rules:
  default: false
  custom:
  - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"^container_network_receive_bytes_total$"}'
    resources:
      overrides:
        namespace: 
          resource: "namespace"
        pod: 
          resource: "pod"
    name:
      matches: ""
      as: "bytes_per_second"
    metricsQuery: sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>})) by (<<.GroupBy>>)
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you tried a simpler query to debug? Also can you paste the full Error stack , the reason is usually clear there.